# how to use Snackbar after Json response?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I tries to use Snackbar , but it require a view, i have defined the mainlayout as a View Object. And used when Json response completed.
But i dont see any snackbar popup ?
Is there a way to handle that ?
Below is how i handle when parse JSON response.

```
public CityWeather parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response){
    cityWeather=new CityWeather();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"parse1");

    JSONObject resp= response;
    JSONObject detailJo;
    JSONObject cityJo;
    JSONObject aqiJo;
    String aqi;
    String city;
    String nowtemp;
    String condcd;
    String pm25;
    try {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"start parse");
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG,resp.toString());
        JSONArray weatherarrary = resp.getJSONArray(KEY_API);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"start parse2");

        //get Details
        detailJo=weatherarrary.getJSONObject(0);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"start parse3");

        //getAQI
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG,detailJo.toString());
        cityJo=detailJo.getJSONObject(KEY_AQI);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"after send json true");

        //when city not found
        if (cityJo==null){

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"parse fail");
            return cityWeather;
        }

        aqiJo=cityJo.getJSONObject(KEY_CITY);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,aqiJo.toString());

        aqi=aqiJo.getString(KEY_AQI);
        pm25=aqiJo.getString(KEY_PM25);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"parse succss1"+aqi+" "+pm25);

        //get City
        cityJo=detailJo.getJSONObject(KEY_BASIC);
        city=cityJo.getString(KEY_CITY);

        Snackbar.make(mainview,city+"添加成功",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

        //get now temp
        cityJo=detailJo.getJSONObject(KEY_NOW);
        nowtemp=cityJo.getString(KEY_TMP);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"parse succss2"+city+" "+nowtemp);
        //
        cityJo=cityJo.getJSONObject(KEY_COND);
        condcd=cityJo.getString(KEY_CODE);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"parse succss3"+condcd);
        cityWeather=new CityWeather(city,aqi,pm25,Integer.parseInt(nowtemp),Integer.parseInt(condcd));

    }catch (JSONException je){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"JSONexp"+je.toString());
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"parse succss4");
    return cityWeather;
}
```

Comment: Snackbar.make(mainview,city+"添加成功",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: You are missing .show() at the end of Snackbar.make().show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not displaying the `Snackbar` via `show()`

Check if you still have issues after changing:

```
Snackbar.make(mainview,city+"添加成功",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

To:

```
Snackbar.make(mainview,city+"添加成功",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```